# Confusion about square bracket notation in the the Kronecker delta symbol

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions, notation, commutator

I am not sure I understand what the short-hand anti-symmetrization means. I.e. I know that 
$$\delta_{cd}^{[ab]} ~=~ \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{c}^{a}\delta_{d}^{b} - \delta_{c}^{b}\delta_{d}^{a})$$
but how do we expand "bigger" analogues? I.e.
$$\delta_{b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4}^{[a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4]} ~=~ ?$$

What is the order of permutation in this case?

Answer (score 2):

$$ \delta^{[\mu_1\mu_2\ldots \mu_n]}_{\nu_1\nu_2\ldots \nu_n}~=~ \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi\in S_n}{\rm sgn(\pi)} \prod_{i=1}^n \delta^{\mu_{\pi(i)}}_{\nu_i}. $$

More generally,

$$ T^{[\mu_1\mu_2\ldots \mu_n]}~=~ \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi\in S_n}{\rm sgn(\pi)}  T^{\mu_{\pi(1)}\mu_{\pi(2)}\ldots \mu_{\pi(n)}}. $$

Here $S_n$ is the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) of permutations, and $\pi\in S_n$ is a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) with [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) ${\rm sgn(\pi)}$. The [order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29) of $S_n$ is $$|S_n|~=~n!~.$$

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79157/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95133/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Ehm, could you give me an example to understand this better?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic - I suggest you write out an explicit example maybe for $n=3$ or $n=4$.

Comment: I got it. It is rather long to write for $n=4$ or even for $n=3$. I have done it already and thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Marion: Perfect, that saves me the trouble of typing it out. For $n=3$, see also [Prahar's answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79158/2451).