# Square bracket notation of the basis of 16 independent gamma matrices

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions, notation, commutator, dirac-matrices

The question is very simple and I couldn't find an answer.

What the notation $\gamma^{ [ \mu} \gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\rho ]}$ and $\gamma^{ [ \mu} \gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\rho} \gamma^{\sigma ]}$ means?

(From Peskin and Schroeder page 49)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79157/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153613/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to *antisymmetrize* on the indices inside the brackets: Form all permutations, multiply each term by plus or minus one depending on whether the permutation is even or odd, and add the terms together. So the first expression represents 3!=6 terms and the second 4!=24 terms.

If you see curly braces instead of square brackets, it means to *symmetrize*. Add up all permutations, but with a plus sign.